# Windows only shows 2.33Ghz with 2 cpus, when both cpus are 2.33Ghz each

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, multi-core

I have a 2 cpu slot motherboard, each filled with a Intel Xeon E5410, which has 2.33Ghz, and 4 cores. I task manager, it shows 2 cpus, but is only recognising 2.33Ghz, instead of 4.66Ghz (I'm using windows 10 pro):

[image]

I have also tried changing the number of processors in msconfig, but changing it to 2 only gave 2 cores, 8 didn't change anything and 4 only let me use 4 cores.

Can someone advise me on what this is, and how to fix it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: "it shows 2 cpus, but is only recognizing 2.33Ghz, instead of 4.66Ghz" - That isn't how multiple processors frequency works. The frequency of each CPU is 2.33 GHz, and that is what is being reported, what you want reported is not possible.

Comment: If two cars go 50 mph side by side, we don't say they go 100 mph.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - car analogies are the best, and that is a great one

Answer (score 5):

Task Manager is correct.  You have 2 CPUs with four cores each, for a total of 8 cores.  Each individual core can run at up to 2.33GHz.  Having more CPUs and/or more cores does increase speed in most cases, but it is not an additive process.  It is a *parallel* process.

Say I asked you to count to 1000.  You are really good at counting and could at 10Hz, meaning you can count 10 digits a second.  That means you can count to 1000 in 100 seconds.  If I asked you to count to 1000 twice, it would take you 200 seconds.

Now lets say you have an identical twin brother, he wasnt doing anything while you are counting the first 1000.  He wasnt a part of this task.  He cannot contribute.  But with a 2nd task - or thread in the computer world - he can.

Since I asked for 2 countings to 1000.  Now both of you can count to 1000 in the same amount of time, 100 seconds.  You didnt do it twice as fast (20Hz), you did two tasks at 10Mhz in the same amount of time, its just that the two of you did the task in parallel.